# Convert number to Date in Pervasive SQL

Tags: sql, date, pervasive-sql

I am using Actian SQL Version 12.10.067 and trying to output some values.

When running the following query:

```
SELECT Artikel, Deb, Datum,(BeginVoorraad + Mutatie)AS Stand 
from "Fust"
where Artikel IN (97955)
ORDER BY Artikel DESC
```

I get the output:

```
Artikel Deb    Datum   Stand
97955   200256 41865.0 68.0
```

Now I would like to change the Datum number(41865.0) to a real date like 22-08-2018.

I hope someone can help me with the right answer!

Comment: I am using an Actian SQL database also known as Pervasive SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct Answer is

```
CAST((Datum -2) AS datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want the value convert to the date 2014-08-14 (the value in Excel).  If so:

```
SELECT Artikel, Deb,
       '1899-12-30'::date + Datum * interval '1 day',
       (BeginVoorraad + Mutatie)AS Stand 
FROM "Fust"
WHERE Artikel IN (97955)
ORDER BY Artikel DESC;
```

The Excel dates are messed up, because it doesn't recognize 1900 as a non-leap year (look it up on Wikipedia).

If the value is subtly different, just change the base date so you get the value you really want.

EDIT:

In Pervasive, I think this does what you want:

```
dateadd('day', datum, '1899-12-30')
```

Comment: I am not using Excel for this, in my country the date notation is different then commonly used around the world. When running your query it gives a Syntax error.

Comment: @KevinZwemmer . . . "psql" (the original tag) is for Postgresql, and this syntax is correct.  I don't know the right syntax in Pervasive for adding days to a date, but you might know that.

Comment: My knowledge is fairly low on Pervasive as this is my first time trying this. The error tells me it has a problem between the ::, got any clue?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: unrelated, but: in Postgres you could simplify that to `'1899-12-30'::date + Datum::int`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT Artikel, Deb, cast(Datum as datetime),(BeginVoorraad + Mutatie)AS Stand 
from "Fust"
where Artikel IN (97955)
ORDER BY Artikel DESC
```

Comment: That would work if the date is the same every time but I am using a database with 250.000 dates in them so this is not gonna work.

Comment: SELECT Artikel, Deb, cast(Datum as datetime),(BeginVoorraad + Mutatie)AS Stand 
from "Fust"
where Artikel IN (97955)
ORDER BY Artikel DESC

Comment: in SQL cast is used to convert datatype. Give me exact error that you are getting

Comment: [LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine]Syntax Error: SELECT Artikel, Deb, CAST(Datum<<???>>, datetime),(BeginVoorraad + Mutatie)AS Stand from "Fust" where Artikel IN(97955) ORDER BY Artikel DESC